# Click on button with second finger while first is holding on screen

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am creating app for small children. If the child holds phone in his hand, sometimes happens, that he has one finger holding somewhere on screen and he wants to click the button. I want to allow that possibility of clicking in my app.

I have RelativeLayout and inside LinearLayout with two Buttons. While I am holding finger above RelativeLayout it consumes touch with second finger, so I can't detect button.onTouch() with second finger.

Is there any possibility how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the ACTION_POINTER_UP?

[Android MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_POINTER_UP)